# Orange3 build-macos-app.sh shows custom widget category but not widget itself

Tags: orange

I created a custom "viewdicom" widget for Orange3 based on the "Data Sampler" tutorial. Its setup.py is as follows

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    version="1.0.0",
    name="viewdicom",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={"viewdicom": ["icons/*.svg"]},
    install_requires=["rtk"],
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=["Example :: Invalid"],
    entry_points={"orange.widgets": "Radiomics = viewdicom"},
)
```

I pulled the Orange3 Git repo and created a virtualenv for it. When I install the widget into that virtualenv using "pip install -e ." and then run Orange3 itself I correctly see the "viewdicom" widget in its own "Radiomics" category.

All is fine. Then I try to build a Mac OSX app from the Orange3 installation using the following build.sh script that wraps the build-macos-app.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /Applications/Orange3.app
../orange3/scripts/macos/build-macos-app.sh --pip-arg={-e,/Users/ralph/dev/orange3,/Users/ralph/dev/rtk,/Users/ralph/dev/orange3-widgets/rtk/viewdicom,PyQt5} /Applications/Orange3.ap
```

So my custom widget is called "viewdicom" and it uses a library (my own) called "rtk". I'm not sure this is the correct way to include custom libraries and widgets in the *.app build but without them I do not see anything in the *.app content's site-packages.

If I build the app like this and check the contents of the site-packages directory inside the Orange3.app:
    /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

I see the following for "rtk":

[package "rtk" site-packages directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXJKC.png)

and the following for "viewdicom"

[package "viewdicom" site-packages directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O0si.png)

They seem to have been installed inside the Orange3.app. The "installed_files.txt" and "SOURCES.txt" files contain the right source files as far as I can see. The "entry_points.txt" file for "viewdicom" correctly contains

```
[orange.widgets]
Radiomics = viewdicom
```

I'm not sure about the "rtk" library. It's not an Orange3 widget and not an application. I don't know if it also needs an entry point or not.

I cannot understand why the built Orange3.app would correctly show the category "Radiomics" but not the widget "viewdicom".

If anybody has experience with the build-tacos-app.sh script I would be grateful for some tips.

Comment: Try running `/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/Orange -l 4` from the terminal to see a detailed log of widget discovery (or look at `~/Library/Logs/Orange Canvas/canvas.log`)

Comment: Thanks I wil do that!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. It turned out that my widget crashed when it was trying to load Pandas. It had not been included in the install_requires option of setup.py. Now it works fine